# Client closed connection while waiting for request with nginx, puma and Actioncable Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, actioncable

I tried to deploy my Rails app which is contain Actioncable with Puma and Nginx.

So i got from the browser

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://sub.domain.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Then when i check nginx error log i got this

This is my nginx config file

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/app_repo/shared/tmp/sockets/app_repo-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name sub.domain.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/app_repo/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/app_repo/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/app_repo/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  # enables WS support
  location /cable {
      proxy_pass http://puma;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_read_timeout 180;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_read_timeout 180;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  keepalive_timeout 180;
}
```

My puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

plugin :tmp_restart
daemonize true
pidfile 'home/deploy/apps/app_repo/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
```

So how can i fix this and make Actioncable working well on prodeuction server?

Thanks you so much.